# Can I automatically upload pictures to Instagram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram, instagram-api

I know this has been asked before but since it's been so long I'll ask it again, Can I upload pictures to Instagram automatically through the InstagramAPI, if not, is there any other safe way to do it? (preferably using python), I have a very busy schedule and don't have enough time to post pictures, so I wanted to automate the process. 
Here's something I tried using instapy-cli

```
from instapy_cli import client

username = 'my_username'

password = 'my_password'

image = 'image.jpg'

text = 'test caption'

with client(username, password) as cli:
    cli.upload(image, text)
```

Here's the error

```
[IG] not found cookie/cookie_file >> login as default
Error is >>
Error parsing error response: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
    Bad Request

Something went bad.
Please retry or send an issue on https://github.com/b3nab/instapy-cli

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/firmi/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/Projects/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    cli.upload(image, text)
  File "C:\Users\firmi\PycharmProjects\MyProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\instapy_cli\cli.py", line 153, in upload
    raise IOError("Unable to upload.")
OSError: Unable to upload.
```

I've tried to use 'instabot', 'InstagramAPI', 'instagram-private-api' and others

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I have tried some libraries that claim to have functions to upload photos, but they all just return errors.

Comment: Hi, show to us what you've been tried. Provide some code to help us to analyze where are you doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As demonstrated by Self Engineered in [their blog post](https://medium.com/@selfengineeredd/how-to-post-on-instagram-using-python-fd8b08050a85), this can be done with the [instapy-cli](https://pypi.org/project/instapy-cli/) package:

> ```
> pip install instapy-cli
> ```

> ```py
> from instapy_cli import client
>
> username = 'username' #your username
> password = '**********' #your password 
> image = 'Hi_instagram.png' #here you can put the image directory
> text = 'Here you can put your caption for the post'
>    
> with client(username, password) as cli:
>    cli.upload(image, text)
> ```

For more details, refer to the blog post.

Comment: I did the same exact thing but it gives me an error "IOError("Unable to upload.")"

Comment: can you please add the error logs, IOError means that it might not be able to find the picture location,

Comment: I added them on the post

Comment: doesn't work, got a bunch of errors: [IG] not found cookie/cookie_file >> login as default
No handlers could be found for logger "instagram_private_api.errors"
Error is >>
    Not Found

Something went bad.
Please retry or send an issue on https://github.com/b3nab/instapy-cli

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_to_instagram.py", line 9, in <module>
    cli.upload(image, text) 
  File "/home/paul/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instapy_cli/cli.py", line 153, in upload
    raise IOError("Unable to upload.")
IOError: Unable to upload.

Comment: It was working like a charm at a time I posted answer, sorry if it's not working now.  :(

Answer (score 1):

Install instabot:

```
pip install instabot
```

Then make a new python script:

```
vim upload_to_instagram.py
```

Put this into the script:

```
from instabot import Bot 
bot = Bot() 
bot.login(username = "user_name",  
          password = "user_password") 
bot.upload_photo("Technical-Scripter-2019.jpg", 
                 caption ="Technical Scripter Event 2019")
```

Save the script and close it, then run it with:

```
python upload_to_instagram.py
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but every time I run the code a config file is created, which I need to delete before every run for it to work but I have a schedule to run the code every hour. Problem is while the code is running the config file is being written to, so I'm unable to delete it.